# How to identify parameters sent from ArcMap to geoprocessing service on ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, web-service, arcgis-rest-api

I have a question regarding the use of ESRI geoprocessing services and maybe some of you can give me a hint for the following "problem"...

I have set up a geoprocessing service which should solve a Vehicle Routing Problem on a given network. If I call the service via Rest URL with the expected parameters the service does not calculate a route, but does also not print any error messages. The service itself works correct. I have tested the functionality by calling the service via ArcMap by entering the expected parameters via the GUI. The parameters are send to the service on the server, the results are calculated there and finally visualized in ArcMap. Thus I think the service works correct.

Now the question: Is there any software that can show me how the request is build up / how the parameters are send from ArcMap to the server? My idea is to copy the syntax and to use it in the Rest URL. I have already tried Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) but it doesn´t show any paramters. Another idea was to look at the log files on the server, but also here I cannot identify any parameters.

Comment: Have you tried just running the service once from the ArcGIS Server Manager and copying the URL that it builds up and submits?  Out of interest are you using 10.0 or 10.1?

Comment: Have you tied Fiddler? http://fiddler2.com/ I've had success from it in the past.

Comment: btw it is ArcGIS 10.1.

Comment: Consider using ArcGIS Viewer for Flex for testing the functionality of the VRP GP service you've created. It has support for the GP service input parameters and obtaining the results to the client side, so you can check first that the service works fine with the REST before digging into the REST API and all the parameters. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-viewer/concepts/index.html#/Geoprocessing_widget/01m30000003t000000/